# How to interpret the marginal effects of a logit model

Tags: regression, logistic, marginal-effect

I’m trying to run a binary logit model to study the commute distance between place of residence and place of work for individuals. I’m reporting the marginal effects. I’m having hard time interpreting the results and I would really appreciate if you can help me with that. I divided commute distance into 2 categories (0 if commute > 0 and <=100 and I called it low) and (1 if commute > 100 and I called it long).

My independent variables are age (25-64 years old), marital status (single as a reference category), educational attainment (having a high school as reference category), presence of kids, homeownership (tenur) and female.

My issue is how I would interpret the results in a binary logit model, for example

1- The age variable came back with a negative sign in the low commute (0-100) does that means that I can conclude that: as people get older, they will commute less in the 0-100 km range? Does that automatically implies that, as people get older they will commute more in the above 100 range or not necessarily?

2- A positive marginal effect for the married variable (reference single): I can say that a married individual will commute more than a single individual in the 0-100 commute. Again, does that imply that a single individual will commute above 100 more than a married one?

3- Female variable: a female will commute more in the 0-100 km patterns compared to male which will imply that males commute more than females in the above 100 pattern.

Comment: Why are you using logistic regression? It seems a bit odd, since you are modelling commute distance, why not simply linear regression?

Comment: My dependent variable is a binary variable. 0 if commute 0-100 km and 1 if commute > 100. Linear regression is usually used to predict a continuous dependent variable (not my case)

Comment: Yes but you say you divided commutedistance into binary, which leads me to think you also have the "underlying" variable measuring commute distance, so my question is why would you recode it to binary in the first place?

Comment: From my understanding (and I'm new to this), the use of OLS will assume that the dependent variable is normally distributed. With a binary variable, this assumption is violated.

Comment: Allright. You are probably right, I'm also quite new at this.

Comment: For 1, I would just say that "in the population of interest, older individuals tend to have longer commutes." You can't necessarily say that increasing age causes a longer commute.